# Use PHP get_defined_vars to print names of all arrays with < n elements

Tags: php, debugging, variables

I'm trying to use PHP's get_defined_vars function to print a list of variable names where the variable has less than n elements (we only want arrays here).

I can get it to print out the contents of each relevant array itself, but can't figure out how to make it just give the name of the variable.

Trying to use this:

```
//Get all of the variables as an array
$variables = get_defined_vars();

foreach ( $variables as $item ) {

    if ( is_array($item) ) {

        //Count the number of elements in this array
        $elements = count($item);

        //If there's less than 3 elements, print the array
        if ( $elements < 3 ) {
            echo "<p>";
            print_r($item);
            echo "</p><br />";
        }

    }

}
```

As I say, that gives the contents of any array variable with less than 3 elements. Any idea how to get it to just give the name of the variable? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use `foreach($variables as $varName => $item)` to also get the name of the variable:

```
foreach ( $variables as $varName => $item ) {

    if ( is_array($item) ) {

        //If there's less than 3 elements, print the array
        if ( count($item) < 3 ) {
            echo "<p>$varName</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, just figured it out too. Thanks for your answer! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

if you did this:

```
foreach(get_defined_vars() as $key=>$val)
{
   //$key gives the name of the array

}
```